# How do you define the domain and range of the variables for a plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics, complex

How do I define the domain to be only reals and the range to be only complexes?

Everytime I plot using ComplexPlot[], I get a C->C function so there are basically too many variables to plot and I get a color plot (I think that's what they're called).

However, I want to plot R->C for this function. How do I define that using the complex plot function? Or is another function I don't know about.

Question 2:
Also can this be implemented any way? So can I customise my plot to be real input on x-axis, complex input on y-axis, and real output on the z-axis with color representing complex output? Is it possible to shift these around (complex output and real output as color)? and what is the default, because mathematica doesn't have good axis labelling so it's hard to tell.

```
B[x_] := ((1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]))^x - (1/2 (1 - Sqrt[5]))^x)/Sqrt[5];
ComplexPlot[B[x], {x, -10 - 10 I, 10 + 10 I}]
```

Comment: You need an underscore (`Blank`) in your function definition, as `B[x_]:=`.  Then, plot the Argand diagram with `ParametricPlot[ReIm@B[x], {x, -10, 10},
 PlotRange -> All]` or the real and imaginary parts with `ReImPlot[B[x], {x, -10, 10}]`.

Comment: @LouisB oh, sorry I made a typo, yes I know that there is supposed to be an underscore, but thanks for explaining the rest of the question.